# Existing PDF to PDF/A "conversion"

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to make an existing pdf into pdf/a-1b. I understand that itext cannot convert a pdf to pdf/a in the sense making it pdf/a compliant. But it definitely can flag the document as pdf/a. However, I looked at various examples and I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. The major problem is that

```
writer.PDFXConformance = PdfWriter.PDFA1B;
```

does not work anymore. First PDFA1B is not recognized, second, pdfwriter seems to have been rewritten and there is not much information about that.
It seems the only (in itext java version) way is:

```
PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B);
```

But that requires a document type, ie. it can be used when creating a pdf from scratch.

Can someone give an example of pdf to pdf/a conversion with the current version of itextsharp?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a valid reason for doing this but apparently you have one.

The conformance settings in iText are intended to be used with a `PdfWriter` and that object is (generally) only intended to be used with new documents. Since iText was never intended to convert documents to conformance that's just the way it was built.

To do what you want to do you could either just open the original document and update the appropriate tags in the document's dictionary or you could create a new document with the appropriate entries set and then import your old document. The below code shows the latter route, it first creates a regular non-conforming PDF and then creates a second document that says it is conforming even though it may or may not. See the code comments for more details. This targets iTextSharp 5.4.2.0.

```
//Folder that we're working from
var workingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

//Create a regular non-conformant PDF, nothing special below
var RegularPdf = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "File1.pdf");
using (var fs = new FileStream(RegularPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}

//Create our conformant document from the above file
var ConformantPdf = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "File2.pdf");
using (var fs = new FileStream(ConformantPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {

        //Use PdfSmartCopy to get every page
        using (var copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, fs)) {

            //Set our conformance levels
            copy.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_3);
            copy.PDFXConformance = PdfWriter.PDFX1A2001;

            //Open our new document for writing
            doc.Open();

            //Bring in every page from the old PDF
            using (var r = new PdfReader(RegularPdf)) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= r.NumberOfPages; i++) {
                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(r, i));
                }
            }

            //Close up
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Just to be 100% clear, this **WILL NOT MAKE A CONFORMANT PDF**, just a document that says it conforms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The example provides PDFX conformance. How, would I set the document to be PDF/A-1B conformant? The examples I found mention PDFA1B instead of PDFX1A2001, however, in itextsharp 5.4.4 there is no definition of PDFA1B, I went through the source and there is really no mention of PDFA1B.

Comment: I don't have a compiler in front of my but it looks like this has your answer: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PDFA1A-amp-PDFA1B-td4655849.html

Comment: This is actually what I already came across, the problem is how to incorporate the syntax of PdfAWriter into your example which uses PdfSmartCopy. What I believe I need to do is to import pages into document class and then use this document class with PdfAWrite. Do you have some idea how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: I actually used this example as a basis to _strip_ PDF/A compliance. ;)